# Prove that x(t) = U(t,s)x(s) ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Let $X(t)$ be a fundamental matrix of the equation $\dfrac{dx}{dt} = A(t) x$ and let $U(t, s) = X(t)X^{-1}(s)$. I want to show that $x(t) = U(t,s)x(s)$.

**My Attempt :**

(1):$$X^{-1}(t)x(t) = X^{-1}(t)A(t)x(t)$$, moreover we have that :

(2):$$(X^{-1}(t)x(t))' = (X^{-1}(t))'x(t) + X^{-1}(t)x'(t)$$ with the fact that $(X^{-1}(t))' = -X^{-1}(t)X'(t)X^{-1}(t)$.

Futhermore, we know that $X'(t) = A(t)X(t)$, then $A(t) = X'(t)X^{-1}(t)$, then we have $(X^{-1}(t))' = -X^{-1}(t)A(t)$. We replace it in (2) and so we obtain :

$(X^{-1}(t)x(t))' = -X^{-1}(t)A(t)x(t) + X^{-1}(t)x'(t) \Rightarrow X^{-1}(t)A(t)x(t) = X^{-1}(t)x'(t) - (X^{-1}(t)x(t))'$. We replace it in (2) and so we have :

$X^{-1}(t)x'(t) = X^{-1}(t)x'(t) - (X^{-1}(t)x(t))' \Rightarrow (X^{-1}(t)x(t))' = 0$, by integration between s and t we obtain :
$$X^{-1}(t)x(t) - X^{-1}(s)x(s) = 0 \Rightarrow x(t) = U(s,t)x(s)$$

I'm wondering if somebody can just check it. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: No need to differentiate $U(t,s)x(s)= x(t) x^{-1}(s)x(s)= x(t)$

Comment: @lcv : $X$ and $x$ are really different objects here.

Comment: @LutzLehmann True, but there's still no need to differentiate. From $U(t, s) = X(t)X(s)^{−1}$ we have $X(t) = U(t,s) X(t)$. This tells us that $x(t) = U(t,s) x(t)$ for _some_ solutions $x$. One only needs to recall what a fundamental matrix is, and then it should be obvious that in fact $x(t) = U(t,s) x(t)$ for _all_ solutions $x$.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz  does it mean that my proof is not correct or just too complicated?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz : You need to be careful with the time parameters. But indeed, any solution has $x(t)=X(t)c$, so that $x(t)=X(t)[X(s)^{-1}x(s)]=U(t,s)x(s)$.

Comment: Your proof is correct but looks too complicated. You should look up what you can use of the properties of a fundamental matrix, no need to prove these properties again.

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz  You made a mistake second line of your comment $X(t)$ on both sides. It should be $X(s)$ I guess on the left side ..

Comment: You're both right, of course. Unfortunately, I cannot edit my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to compute with the derivatives of the inverse matrix? Set $x(t)=U(t,s)c_s$, then $x(s)=c_s$ and
$$
x'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}(U(t,s)c_s)=X'(t)X(s)^{-1}c_s=AX(t)X(s)^{-1}c_s=Ax(t),
$$
so that indeed $x(t)=U(t,s)c_s$ is a solution of the linear ODE system. By uniqueness it is the only one that passes through $x(s)=c_s$ at time $s$. This shows that in general $x(t)=U(t,s)x(s)$ for any solution $x$.

Comment: I don't know it is the only thing that it comes to my mind first... I'm wondering if that means my proof is false?