# Show that $T(t,s) = X(t)X^{-1}(s)$ does not depend on the choice of the fundamental matrix $X$ of the ODE $\frac{dx}{dt} = A(t)x$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing

My problem is the following:

Considering a fundamental matrix $X(t)$ of the equation $\frac{dx}{dt} = A(t)x$, I would like to show that $T(t,s) = X(t)X^{-1}(s)$ does not depend on the choice of that fundamental matrix $X(t)$.

I believe this means that considering another fundamental matrix, say $Y(t)$, we need to show that:

$$X(t)X^{-1}(s) = Y(t)Y^{-1}(s)$$

Actually I don't know how $Y^{-1}(t)X(t)$ depends on $t$, but it seems that it would get me to the right answer. Any idea how to find it?

Comment: It is indeed, as can be seen in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4118458/prove-that-xt-ut-sxs-ode, but is this uniqueness enough to conclude on the equality $X(t)X(s)^{-1} = Y(t)Y(s)^{-1}$ for any fundamental matrix $Y(t)$ ? I'm not sure this point is clear for me

Comment: Of course.. thank you @RicardoCavalcanti !